# Error en Ordenamiento y posterior renderizado de productos en react

Tags: reactjs, useeffect

estoy aprendiendo react, y estoy haciendo un ecommerce con fines de practica, mi problema radica al momento de renderizar las cards despues de filtrarlas. si hago un console.log de los productos, estan ordenados, pero no se visualizan los cambios, no se renderizan.  y ya estan en un useEffect.  adjunto mi codigo, si alguien me puede dar una mano.

como info, estoy usando useContext, en el que los envio los filtros a un context y consumo desde ahi.. todos los demas filtros, como precio y categoria funcionan bien. solo el ordenamiento me falla.
Gracias.

```html
const Cards = () => {
  const globalData = useContext(DataContext)
  const products = globalData.products

  const [productsRender, setProductsRender] = useState(products)


  const { filters } = useContext(FiltersContext)
  const {minPrice, maxPrice, searched, catSelected, orderBy, sortBy} = filters


  useEffect(() => {
  //function to search items with the searchBar, and filter the results with the range selector. 
  let productsFiltered = products.filter((product) => {
    const priceInRange = product.price >= minPrice && product.price <= maxPrice;
    const matchesCategory = catSelected === 'all' || catSelected === product.category;
    const matchesSearch = searched === '' || product.name.includes(searched);
    return priceInRange && matchesCategory && matchesSearch;
  });


  //Order && Sort products already  filtered.
  const productosOrdered = productsFiltered.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === 'price')
      if (orderBy === 'from_lower')
        return (a.price - b.price)
      else
        return (b.price - a.price)
    else if (sortBy === 'rating')
      if (orderBy === 'from_lower')
        return (a.rating - b.rating)
      else
        return (b.rating - a.rating)
  })
  
  setProductsRender(setProductsRender);

  }, [minPrice, maxPrice, catSelected, searched, orderBy, sortBy ]);

  return (
    <div className='grid gap-6 mx-10 mt-32 md:mt-40 grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 2xl:grid-cols-5 3xl:grid-cols-6 justify-center ' >
      {productsRender.map(product => ( 
        <Card
          key={product.id}
          id={product.id}
          title={startCase(product.title)}
          description={product.description}
          price={product.price}
          image={product.img}
          category={product.category}
          rating={product.rating}
        />
      ))
    }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: Dentro de `useEffect,` esto se ve sospechoso `setProductsRender(setProductsRender);` parece que debería ser `setProductsRender(productosOrdered);` prueba eso y avisanos del resultado, pued que tambien haya problemas de referencia.

Comment: hola gracias por responder... no se  en que momento puse eso ahi  tal vez ya estaba muy cansado. pero si estaba  como setProductsRender(productosOrdered). y lo acabo de revisar nuevamente, y sigue sin funcionar .  incluso chatgpt me dice que esta bien el codigo. ya no se que hacer 